# I want minus one month in date in vuejs

Tags: javascript

I am getting a date in the following format `"2020-05-02"` i want minus one month in javascript.
I am getting a date using the Date() function of javascript.

how can I minus one month from the date?

Comment: Do you want using `moment.js` libary?

Comment: `yourdate.setMonth(yourdate.getMonth() - 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**minus one month** is a very subjective thing. What will be the the minus one month for 31st May? 30th April? If yes, then minus one month for 30th May?

If both should return 30th April, a code like this would be better:

```js
function minusOneMonth(d) { 
  const month = d.getMonth();
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
  while (month === d.getMonth()) {
      d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
  }
  return d;
}
console.log(minusOneMonth(new Date("2020-05-31")))
console.log(minusOneMonth(new Date("2020-05-30")))
```

Comment: you are right I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Get the month and minus one month to it and set to date again.

```js
const dateStr = "2020-05-02";

const setMonth1Back = (str) => {
  const date = new Date(str);
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
  return date;
};
console.log(setMonth1Back(dateStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setMonth() function from the Date object

```
const date = new Date();
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() -1);
```

Comment: Getting error. "viewDate.getMonth is not a function"